# Using slang in a Scientific Paper

Tags: publications, writing, writing-style

We are writing a paper about an algorithm that takes a group of solutions and sorts them by their likelihood of being equal to the one and only 'good solution'.

Internally, we refer to this 'good solution' as **meromero**, which is a Mexican street slang for 'the most important' or the precisely for 'the one and only'.

I like the word because it allows naming an important concept with a funky and short sound. Also, it forces you to draw your eyes towards it, creating some kind of highlight about the ideas related to this 'one and only good solution'.

However, I'm not sure of using it, precisely because it is a slang word and I don't remember ever reading a paper using slang words.

Therefore, my question is:

**Is using a slang word to name a concept bad taste in a scientific paper?**

Notice that this is merely a personal curiosity, we have already choosen not to use the word.

Comment: For what it's worth, "meromero" means something completely different in Japanese so you might confuse Japanese readers. In Japanese "meromero" (メロメロ) means either to be "madly in love" or to be "falling down drunk".

Comment: @Pharap That settles it. Now I totally need to find a reason to name something "meromero."

Comment: For the benefit of non-Mexican readers, it's important to point out that the transcription "mero mero" (with a space) is equally (and probably way more) common than the OP's.

Comment: Find a good scientific (B)Acronym and call it M.E.R.O.M.E.R.O.

Comment: Why does the "one and only good solution" needs a new word, rather than *optimum* or *optimal solution*?

Comment: I would suggest "etalon solution" or simply "etalon". And, while it's not needed to rename "best solution", if you actually find some new object (for example, your algorithm), you can name it whatever you want. No one knows but I think quarks got their name because "quark" is the sound that frog makes. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quark#Etymology

Comment: @ThePhoton: You are right, it does not need a new word. I was just curious about the possibility and behold! Such a nice discussion about it! How many things I've learned from the comments and answers! :)

Comment: What @Pharap says is not necessarily a problem. For many words there are other meanings in some languages. Extreme example - Finnish people shouldn't say "tasty" in Latvian restaurants as "maukas" means "whores" here. We even have [some](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ogre,_Latvia) enjoyably-named places for English tourists as well as related merchandise ( http://ronin.com.ua/posts_picture/000/000/471/ogre_original.jpg ) for the Lenin's centennial. I don't think the Soviet people were aware of the English meaning at the time :)

Comment: @Džuris There's a difference in this case though. Firstly slang isn't as widely recognised as well known words like "tasty", "whore" and "ogre". Secondly place names are a bit of an exception - in 2013 the twinning of the Scottish village of Dull in Perthshire with the American town of Boring in Oregon welcomed a link to a third settlement - Australia's Bland Shire. Those arguments made, I agree that I wouldn't necessarily use double meanings as a major argument as to why it's a bad idea, especially when there are more substantial arguments available.

Comment: *it allows naming an important concept with a funky and short sound*  This ought to be your last concern in a paper.  The objective is to reach *and be understood* by the widest audience.  Use an expression that conveys meaning or an abbreviation for that expression if it's too long to repeatedly use.  Funky is for YouTube, precise meaning is for academic papers.

Comment: [Here's](http://epubs.siam.org/doi/abs/10.1137/1.9781611974973.56) an algorithm published in a reputable conference that has the acronym R.O.F.L.M.A.O.!  I say go for it, science needs be at least a _little_ fun...

Comment: there is also a serious article which contains the word "bullshit" 197 times: http://journal.sjdm.org/15/15923a/jdm15923a.html

Comment: What's wrong with ***'unique solution'***?

Comment: If you are naming something, it's really your choice how you wish to do it. There have been lots of whimsical names given to concepts in various scientific fields: e.g. "quark", "Big Bang", "Theory of Everything", "imaginary number", "Witch of Agnesi", "Sonic Hedgehog (protein)", "Just Another Kinase (JAK)" (which unfortunately was retconned by the humourless into "Janus Kinase"). So etymology is really up to you. Don't use slang in the general text of your paper though.

Comment: I know that it isn't slang but I felt that the Sonic Hedgehog gene needs to be mentioned here, which while it may seem 'odd' has certainly succeeded in making me remember it (which would suggest that picking a 'unique' word/term can have merit).

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Your goal in writing scientific papers is for the language to be as intelligible as possible. That is, you want to use language which won't hinder people who are trying to read your paper.

The disadvantage of slang is that it is often not intelligible to many people (especially non-native speakers), and may be idiosyncratic to specific groups. Therefore, if your goal is for the paper to be as intelligible as possible, you would want to avoid using slang.

In addition, scientific writing tends to be relatively formal, which is why slang will often look inappropriate and out of place.

Some papers which mention that you should avoid using slang:

http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1443950600900817

http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/micr.20960/full

It's possible that conventions will be different in your field. When in doubt, look at other publications and use them to guide you.

Comment: Personally I find that a lot of names and wording are just selected to be fancy or get attention. It would be nice indeed if we could use a sober and formal language...

Comment: @Alchimista  I don't think science always needs to be sober and formal.  It should be at least a _little_ fun, at least _sometimes_ !

Comment: Science is fun independently. Moreover, I agree with you. But the entire field of plastic electronics is named upon plastic, and there are not plastic in there except for some of the bodily substrate. For example.

Answer (score 33):

Mathematicians frequently come up with questionable names drawn from a variety of questionable sources. And then at some point there will be the inevitable MathOverflow thread about why such-and-such is named what it is. I personally rather like "meromero," but in the context you're describing, I don't see how it's an improvement over saying "unique 'good' solution," where you define what exactly you mean by "good."

Comment: Indeed, I also like the word as a matter of personal taste only :)

Comment: Can I use it myself? Not that I have anything in mind at the moment, but it's too good a word to pass up.

Comment: :D sure! you can use it!

Comment: Mathematician here. I can confirm that if I'd read in a paper: "We define the **meromero** to be the unique solution of Eq. (7) satisfying..." then I would find it a bit odd, but it would certainly not be the strangest terminology I've encountered. A famous example of foreign slang being imported as mathematical terminology is "shtuka" - see http://www.ams.org/notices/200301/what-is.pdf

Comment: It's an improvement in the sense that "meromero" is shorter than "unique good solution". It's also unambiguous (once it has been defined), whereas "good" could be taken in a general sense or a specific one.

Comment: @bubba: In this case I'd be inclined to refer to the "unique good solution" as the "optimum" - it's even shorter, and already has the right connotation, even for those unfamiliar with Mexican slang. Of course you'd still need to define it clearly.

Answer (score 12):

Honestly, I don't think I'd do it in a scientific paper. There are lots of "internal" name for things in my own lab that I'd never put in a scientific paper. This is especially true if there's not an obvious meaning for it - which is usually true for slang.

The one place people do seem to get away with it is clever acronyms.

I don't know that I'd call it "bad taste", given said slang term isn't *offensive*. I'd just call it "weird word choice".

Answer (score 10):

Don't use it, unless - with very good reason - you describe something new that needs a word. Readers won't understand what you are talking about, and it seems that, in this case, our common language is already sufficient to describe what you mean.

Answer (score 6):

I will be a slightly contrarian voice here. I think naming your algorithm something memorable is a good idea and if there is a story to go with why you named it that way, all the better. Would [CRISPR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CRISPR) be all the rage (in the media) right now if it had some sort of [daft unpronounceable acronym](http://www.bmj.com/content/349/bmj.g7092)? Of course it doesn't hurt that it is revolutionary but the name being memorable is important for larger recognition.

Does it really matter what 'wiki' meant when they used it to name Wikipedia? It now means Wikipedia.

I took a class from [Rich Sutton](http://incompleteideas.net/sutton/) and he mentioned how important the name of [SARSA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State-Action-Reward-State-Action) was in having the algorithm gain popularity. If it is a word that is pronounceable in most languages, memorable and even fun to say, go for it.

Other algorithms like [NEAT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neuroevolution_of_augmenting_topologies) and [HyperNEAT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HyperNEAT) have benefited from being pronounceable and memorable.

You will be fighting for academic funding for the rest of your life, you might as well realize now that science like most things in life operates by the principles of marketing. For what it's worth I like the name meromero but you might want to do some Googling to make sure it doesn't mean some offensive thing somewhere in the world before you assign it to your baby.

Comment: I agree. There is also a hugh difference between using slang as part of the running text (which certainly should be avoided) and using a slang word to name something e.g. an algorithm.

Answer (score 4):

Computer science has a tradition, when a new name is needed for a concept, of coining a whimsical term in preference to the approach in the traditional sciences of choosing something that sounds vaguely Latin, Greek, or pompous. Sometimes people invent a completely new term, such as byte or trie or arity, sometimes they adopt an English word and give it a specialised meaning, such as widget, closure, bag, or web, others prefer acronyms or descriptive names ("red-black tree"). Basically, anything is allowed, and perfectly respectable.

You should consider first whether a new term is really needed, taking into account that your readers will probably have to refer back frequently to the place where you introduced it; and secondly whether the term is memorable. A term is more likely to be memorable if it isn't completely arbitrary. A term from English slang might make you seem less-than-serious to some readers, but slang in an obscure language is unlikely to suffer that drawback.

Comment: I'm not sure I'd characterize the second most common native language (after Mandarin) as "obscure".

Answer (score 3):

> Is using a slang word to name a concept bad taste in a scientific paper?

Not in being slang. You do need to make sure that:

- your slang-named term is **clearly defined** without no slang in the definition.
- you **aren't assuming people are aware of the term's connotations** (they might not even today, and in several years it may go out of use completely).
- using that term **serves a valid purpose**, like memorability.
- the term is **not offensive** to the readers (or a social group of people etc).

Other than that I think you're fine.